# Space between html elements in shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

In my shiny applications, I have some html tags incorporated. But right now there is no spacing between them. SO wanted to get some help in having the space. Below is the code

```
      HTML(paste0(as.character(tags$h3("Review")), tags$h4(style = "font-style: italic;", format(nrow(df1)), digits =2, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE),br(),
                  tags$h4(tags$li("Apple",icon("apple"), formatC(df1$vl,big.mark = ",")))))
```

Comment: Please, provide a reproducible example to see better what the ui is showing.

Comment: `br()` or `"<br>"` will add vertical line spacing. `" "` will add horizontal spacing. If you want things aligned in columns, you can use `fluidRow(column(a,...),column(b,...),...)` where a,b,... add up to 12.